# Deploying multiple applications on google app engine and amazon aws

Tags: google-app-engine, amazon-ec2

Can i develop multiple applications on Google app engine or Amazon AWS??
Does it violate any of the Google app engine and Amazon AWS rules??
Plz advice me on this topic

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can have multiple applications. But for Google there is a limit of [10 applications per developer](http://code.google.com/appengine/kb/general.html#create). In Amazon there is no limit (other than capacity) of number of servers you can buy and no one really asks how many applications are there, unless you perform illegal actions with it (eg. spam).

Answer (score 0):

on Google AppEngine you can't use multiple applications as a way to avoid fees for you application.

So your applications should be different, and you can't deploy many instances of the same application so you get more 'free' allocation.

From the [GAE terms of service](http://code.google.com/appengine/terms.html)

> 4.4. You may not develop multiple Applications to simulate or act as a single Application or otherwise access the Service in a manner
>   intended to avoid incurring fees.